# Server.MapPath not found in Asp.Net MVC project

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I need to get the path to app_data but from a lower layer then the project folder that has my controllers. I'm trying to access it from a service layer but "Server" in "Server.MapPath" isn't found and no intellisense if finding it!

> yogaSpace.SpaceThumbnail = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(
>                       System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Images/no-image.png")));

Answer (score 1):

Probably because you're now using a more current framework and need to use the currently implemented method:

```
System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(HttpServerUtility.MapPath("~/App_Data/Images/no-image.png")));
```

[System.Web.HttpServerUtility.MapPath()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath(v=vs.110).aspx)